# AWS database solution for storing non-relational data

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Whats the best AWS database for the below requirement

- I need to store around 50,000 - 1,00,000 entries in the database.
- Each of the entry would have a String as a key and a Json array as the value.
- I should be able to retrieve the JSON array using the key.
- The size of JSON data is around 20-30KB
- I expect around 10,000 - 40,000 reads per hour.
- Around 50,000 - 1,00,000 writes/week
- I have to consider the cost as well.
- Ease of integration/development

I am bit confused between MongoDB, DynamoDB and PostgreSQL. Please share your thoughts on this.

Comment: What kind of load do you expect uniform or spiky  ?

Comment: Its not uniform. The reads and write could be as low as 2000 and as high as 40,000 per hour.

Answer (score 1):

**DynamoDB:-**

DynamoDB is a fully managed proprietary NoSQL database service that supports key-value and document data structures. For the typical use case that you have described in OP, it would serve the purpose.

> DynamoDB can handle more than 10 trillion requests per day and support
>   peaks of more than 20 million requests per second.

DynamoDB has good AWS SDK for all operations. The [read and write capacity units](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadWriteCapacityMode.html) can be configured for the table.

> DynamoDB tables using on-demand capacity mode automatically adapt to
>   your application’s traffic volume. On-demand capacity mode instantly
>   accommodates up to double the previous peak traffic on a table. For
>   example, if your application’s traffic pattern varies between 25,000
>   and 50,000 strongly consistent reads per second where 50,000 reads per
>   second is the previous traffic peak, on-demand capacity mode instantly
>   accommodates sustained traffic of up to 100,000 reads per second. If
>   your application sustains traffic of 100,000 reads per second, that
>   peak becomes your new previous peak, enabling subsequent traffic to
>   reach up to 200,000 reads per second.

One point to note is that it doesn't allow to query the table based on non-key attributes. This means if you don't know the hash key of the table, you may need to do full table scan to get the data. However, there is a **Secondary Index** option which you can explore to get around the problem. You may need to have all the **Query Access Patterns** of your use case before you design and make informed decision.

**MongoDB:-**

[MongoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quickstart/latest/mongodb/overview.html) is not a fully managed service on AWS. However, you can setup the database using AWS service such as EC2, VPC, IAM, EBS etc. This requires some AWS cloud experience to setup the database. The other option is to use [MongoDB Atlas service](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas/aws-mongodb?utm_medium=referral&utm_source=aws_quickstarts).

MongoDB is more flexible in terms of querying. Also, it has a powerful aggregate functions. There are lots of tools available to query the database directly to explore the data like SQL.

In terms of Java API, the [Spring MongoDB](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-mongodb) can be used to perform typical database operation. There are lots of open source frameworks available on various languages for MongoDB (example [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/) Nodejs) as well.

The MongoDB has support for many programming languages and the APIs are mature as well.

**PostgreSQL:-**

PostgreSQL is a fully managed database on AWS.

> PostgreSQL has become the preferred open source relational database
>   for many enterprise developers and start-ups, powering leading
>   geospatial and mobile applications. Amazon RDS makes it easy to set
>   up, operate, and scale PostgreSQL deployments in the cloud.

I think I don't need to write much about this database and its API. It is very mature database and has good APIs.

**Points to consider:-**

1. Query Access Pattern
2. Easy setup
3. Database maintenance
4. API and frameworks
5. Community support